# Does head->val takes more time than head.val?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I just want to know that using a pointer changes time complexity. To be precise does my time change if I use head.val instead of head->val. Or can I know which one is better.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In most cases, it won't matter a bit.  But it necessarily depends on the language and what you're doing with it.  What language are you using?

Comment: I am using c++. I am practicing in a famous OJ. There I found a similar algo leading my algo using head.val. Almost every thing else is similar.

Comment: Please post a minimal example. head.val and head->val generally mean completely different things, so it is diffucult to use the term "better" to differentiate them. If you mean using a reference vs a pointer, there is virtually no difference on most systems.

Comment: OK for the example, I have solved a question in an Online Judge using a function with parameters, the pointers(i.e head->val). I found that the same algorithm with values as parameters(i.e head.val) has less running time. So I was confused whether the referencing and dereferencing takes extra time?